# Data Recovery: Accessing HDD Files on a different computer

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, gparted, data-recovery

My desktop computer crashed but with a USB adapter I can read it's HDD on my laptop - on my desktop I had a dualboot Ubuntu and Windows, and I have the same on my laptop. When I plug the desktop HDD into my laptop running Ubuntu I can only see the desktop windows files / partition but GParted and lsblk show the other partitions (where my PC ubuntu files are stored). How can I access these files? The goal is just to copy them onto my laptop so I don't lose the data... Thank you!

[image: GParted screenshot]

[image: lsblk screenshot]

Comment: Hi, I think its a bit easier if you copy & paste the text output from lsblk to you post instead of the window. Also I think you should clearly say from where to where you want to copy data (using the names from the lsblk output). Its not so easy to understand what exactly you want. If you want to copy data from your sda1 partition - you should be able to do that with your file manager. The data should be at /media/bwjames/Storage

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and sorry for being unclear! The data in the sda1 partition is the only data I can actually see and access (via the file manger as you indicate) - these are files from my desktop windows partition. 

However the data I am trying to save is the data on the nvme partitions, and while I am not 100% sure which partition I saved the data on, I believe it is nvme0n1p7.

Comment: A small update - I think I understand now how to access the different partitions since the lsblk shows their file path, but I can't find my data and perhaps it was somehow deleted off of the nvme0np6 partition (it's the only thing i can think of why it isn't here) in the crash... Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: If data is corrupted there might be ways to save stuff. There are free tools TestDisk and PhotoRec. If you search for theses here should should find dome info. They are command line tools only, however - no GUI. General rule is to make a copy of the lost partitions first and then work with those tools on the copy.

Comment: Oh and yes, when you see the path, that is where you can copy file files from. If you do not see anything, you should try with admin rights from the command line before giving up, e.g. "sudo ls -la /<pathname>"